# What exception I need to throw if input value was incorrect in web api json converter so server returns 400 instead of 500?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I used a custom JSON converter for timespan values in asp.net (a class inherits from `JsonConverter<TimeSpan>`), but when the client sends a value that is not appropriate for TimeSpan, (for example client sends `45.12` which is not the correct value according to default (`d.mm:hh:ss`) format) I throw an exception.

Then asp.net core returns status 500 to the client that is not correct. I expect asp.net returns 400 with a message saying 'value `45.12` is not the correct value for timespan'.

How can I achieve this?

below is my code:

```
int[] parts = value.Split(':', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();
if (parts.Length != 3)
    throw new Exception($"Unable to parse `{value}` to valid TimeSpan because is not 3 parts");
return new TimeSpan(parts[0] / 24, parts[0] % 24, parts[1], parts[2]);
```

**NOTE**:
I know the above code can be written as `TimeSpan.ParseExat(value)`! but this is not my question!
My question is not about converting string to timespan and vise versa!

My question is about how to handle these situations in the asp.net core environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the controller itself, you should use the [ControllerBase.BadRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method instead of throwing an exception.  You may also want to consider https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/advanced-error-handling-techniques/

Answer (score 0):

You must catch the Exception inside your controller and return a **BadRequest()** to generate a "400 Bad Request" Response.